# Debugging asp.net handler on VS 2010 with WIN 7

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to debug an http handler that I wrote with VS 2008.  I used to be able to Attach to Process w/ VS 2008.  But when I attempt to do the same thing with VS 2010, none of my breakpoints are being hit.

I've modified my web.config file to no avail.  My understanding is that IIS 7 uses application pools, but under what account?  I tried to attach to process with IE 8, but that doesn't appear to work either.

Does anyone else know what I could be missing?

Comment: of interest?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653236/unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server-could-not-start-asp-net-debugging-vs

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking for a process called w3wp. You need to select the "show processes from all users" checkbox in the attach dialog, and sure need to start Visual Studio as administrator (right click the VS icon -> run as administrator).

When there are multiple app pools running on the local machine, you'll find multiple processes with the same name. You can attach to them all, or else there is an extension called "W3WP Advanced Attacher (WADA)", which shows you each process which site it's related to, so, you can only attach to the one you want:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7d740ee7-344a-4550-a272-b6de0071f42f
I myself don't bother and attach to all w3wp processes. My colleague uses the extension successfully, so, not big difference.