# IIS Url Rewrite Module causes "unable to start debugging on the webserver"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, iis-7, url-rewriting

I have just implemented URL Rewrite Module 2.0 for IIS 7 and it seems to be causing a "unable to start debugging on the webserver" error in Visual Studio 2010.

Aside from commenting the  node in the web.config, does anyone know if there might be a fix for this for VS2010?

Thanks

Comment: can you still browse to the root of the app ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See the solution of Kirk Woll here:
[Unable to start debugging on the web server. Could not start ASP.NET debugging VS 2010, II7, Win 7 x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653236/unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server-could-not-start-asp-net-debugging-v)

Just add this rule at the top of your rules

```xml
<rule name="Ignore Default.aspx" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^debugattach\.aspx" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
    <action type="None" />
</rule>
```