# IIS Error: Unable to start debugger on WebServer

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, iis-6

this is what the error I am getting, after pressing CTRL+F5 in asp.net , it keeps loading on VS and after few sec, it shows following message,

**Unable to Start debugging on the web server. The Web Server
did not respond in a timely manner. This may be because another debugger is
Click Help for more information**

I've already done investigation using following links and tried to eradicate the problem

1) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dwesw3ee(v=vs.110).aspx

2) [IIS Url Rewrite Module causes "unable to start debugging on the webserver"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752267/iis-url-rewrite-module-causes-unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-webserver)

your help would be appriciate,

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Open Command Prompt (Run as Administrator)

Write `iisreset /restart`

and then try again :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed with the next steps:

1 . Close all your Visual Studio windows including the project of the mistake

2. Go to path sln project and open with a tool of text edit
   [image]
   [image]
3. Search the localhost variable and change the port to port  :80
   [image]
   [image]
4. Save the file and open the solution with Visual Studio IDE, build and run the project.
   [image]

Comment: Hey Royer, please fill in the “enter image description here”’s - thanks.