# Debugging with VS other than localhost

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I want to debug my application by VS but when the application should run, it should have url like: http:localtesting.com  instead of localhost. I already have localtesting.com in my host file so directly putting that url in my browser opens my IIS default directory page. How can I make my VS to run on that url while debugging? Where should I put that url?
[image]

Edit:
Putting the url in custom web server textbox and running the solution I am getting :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @SteveHobbs said, set it to "Use Custom Web Server and put your URL into that box. Just underneath that section, there should be another section labelled "Debuggers".

Put a tick into the checkbox next to ASP.NET and save the properties.

When you want to debug, go to the debug menu within VS and choose "Attach to Process...".

If you are using IIS, look for the process called 'w3wp.exe' and choose that. After a bit of crunching, perform whatever actions you need on your web app and you will see the debugger land on your breakpoints and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Set it to "Use Custom Web Server" and put your URL into that box.

Edit: 'The unable to debug..' error message is probably a separate issue. Can you debug a brand new site that you can create just to test?

A few things can cause that error. For example, the URL Rewrite module: [Unable to start debugging on the web server. Could not start ASP.NET debugging VS 2010, II7, Win 7 x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653236/unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server-could-not-start-asp-net-debugging-v)