# Visual Studio 2012 hangs, when observing an Collection while debugging ASP.Net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-3.5

for some time i've got a problem debugging my asp.net 3.5 Application with Visual Studio 2012. Each Time i want to observe which values are in an Collection,List or similar classes, Visual Studio hangs for some seconds and then for each Property of the Collection (like Count) there is no Value, but a message which says an timeout occured and i have to step further in the debugger, to activate it again. But when i step further (F10), Visual Studio hangs and i just can kill the w3wp.exe process and start debugging from beginning.

This Problem occurs only in my classic asp.net 3.5 application. Other Asp.net MVC or WinForms applications work just fine!

Anyone an idea?

Comment: What kind of collection is it? Some collections have internal memory management that can cause troubles

Comment: It's mostly the generic List<T>, Collection<T>, that i'm using

Comment: I can confirm that this happens to me daily.  Frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue and stumbled across this post:

[Unable to start debugging on the web server. Could not start ASP.NET debugging VS 2010, II7, Win 7 x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653236/unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server-could-not-start-asp-net-debugging-v)

Dont know how but correcting the username/password of the app pool which was used by the ASP.NET application fixed the issue.

P.S: Application was working fine it not debugged with old app pool credentials.

Hope this helps!