# Unable to start debugging on the web server. The address is not valid for this context

Tags: asp.net, debugging, iis

I was unable to start debugging of web server or attach to process due of error:

**`The address is not valid for this context.`**

Most [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653236/unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server-could-not-start-asp-net-debugging-v) I found is for another error and doesn't provide correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure out that I need to Enable 32-Bit Applications in Application Pool settings:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I am getting same issue, using this it solved that issue.

Answer (score 0):

My error message is similar when starting the project:

"Error while trying to run project: Unable to start program 
'C:\Project\StrictAny\PrensentationLayer\bin\PPEREM.exe'

The address is not valid for this context
"

I solved the problem by switching [Solution Explorer=>Solution Properties=>Active config=>Debug|AnyCUP] to "Debug|x86"

Then the application proceeds in starting.

Weird issue..

hope this helps anyone.