# Getting error "Unable to attach to the process. The address is not valid for this context" while attaching process for debugging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, iis-7

I am trying to host my ASP.Net MVC application on my local IIS 7 and debugging it. For this I host my application on IIS 7 and run application from it. When I am accessing my application from browser I am able to access it and it's working fine. Now for debugging I started my application in browser from IIS and in my VS2012 try to attach to process and select w3wp.exe it not allowing me to attach process for debugging and showing error message as

```
Unable to attach to the process. The address is not valid for this context
```

I tried to run VS2012 in administrator mode too but it won't help. Please tell me what I am doing wrong

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I just reread this.  Are you using IIS UrlRewriter?  Seems like you may have a disconnect between the mapped siteroot and what VS is expecting as the start page.

Comment: I found solution for this issue here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26414278/1619353