# Project won't load on execution and won't pause. Not sure how I can trouble shoot

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, iis-6

I'm working in Visual Studio 2015. The project I pulled and compiled is timing out upon me running it.

A blank web browser opens and just loads until I finally get an error from Visual Studio saying (See image below). I have been trying to follow the trouble shooting advice for this message online, but nothing is fixing my issue. I don't know how I can debug/fix this issue when I have no output to go off of.

What can I do to resolve this issue? Any advice/guidance would be helpful. I'm really lost.

[image]

Comment: Have you gone through this already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653236/unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server-could-not-start-asp-net-debugging-v

Answer (score 0):

It might sound obvious, but the first thing you should do is reboot your PC.

Sometimes I get that error and I have to kill all my browsers and shut down all IIS Processes that are running. But rebooting the PC is the easy way.