# Unable to start debugging on the web server. Operation not supported. Unknown error 0x800040005

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, iis-8

[image]

Getting this on Windows 10 Pro, Visual Studio 2017. ASP .NET Framework 4.6

Comment: Note enabling 32-Bit Applications on IIS did not resolve the issue

Comment: Killed my environment - I am running SharePoint and setting this loses it's mind in IIS (I suspected it would as SP is 64 bit) - the result was interesting - it lost all of the applications. Change back fixed SP but not Visual Studio; in the end it looks like VS 2017 installation broke the environment.

Comment: If this could help --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653236/unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server-could-not-start-asp-net-debugging-v

Comment: Doesn't appear to me web server or .net framework, or VS version related.  I received this error attempting to hit a break point on a Xamarin Android project. Only thing in common was win10 pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the task manager to close all Visual Studio processes currently running and restarting visual studio fixed the issue.

Comment: Restarted my computer and still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 11):

I had this issue and found that removing a https rewrite rule to force www fixed it for me.

Comment: I have not experienced the issue again for quite a while hence cannot test whether or not this works or not.

Comment: My issue was caused by a URL Rewrite rule that forced https

Comment: Sometimes I feel like this bug comes up when IIS just needs to recalculate some internal configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check for, in our case our live config had the DEBUG verb denied:

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering removeServerHeader="true">
    <verbs>
      <!--disable DEBUG verb-->
      <add verb="DEBUG" allowed="false" />
    </verbs>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer was first described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7652063/2245849).

This is most likely a problem with URL Rewrite rules redirecting the **DEBUG** request Visual Studio sends to the **Project Url**:

```
Request URL: https://Project.Url:443/debugattach.aspx
HTTP_METHOD: DEBUG
```

In our case, all `.aspx` requests were being redirected to `index.aspx` so we added this:

```xml
<rule name="DebugBypass" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^.*$"/>
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_METHOD}" pattern="^DEBUG$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="None"/>
</rule>
```

Worked like a charm.

**FYI** - Discovered this by turning on Failed Request Tracing for the Project URL and evaluating the trace log.