# Unable to start debugging on the web server.Could not start ASP.NET debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2013

I am on windows 10, I am using visual studio 2013. In IIS, I have set Enable 32-Bit Applications to TRUE and after this, when I try to debug my application I am getting this error.

> Unable to start debugging on the web server. Could not start ASP.NET debugging. More information may be available by starting the project without debugging

To solve this error, I tried the following:

- restart iis by doing this

  cd %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
  aspnet_regiis.exe -i
- I have set debug attribute to true in web.config file

  ```
  <system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
  ...
  ```

None of the above have worked. Any idea where am I going wrong? What should I do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653236/unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server-could-not-start-asp-net-debugging-v

Comment: Have you tried to do what the error message says? CTRL+F5

Answer (score 0):

Is "W3SVC" service is running in ur machine?
if not try to start the "world wide web publishing service" service in ur machine.