# Visual Studio IIS Debugging error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015

We've just moved our .net 4.6.1 MVC/WebApi application from IISExpress to IIS and are now getting the following exception when trying to debug the application from Visual Studio 2015:

> Unable to start debugging on the web server. The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

We had url rewriting in place that was preventing VisualStudio from accessing /debugattach.aspx.

Excluding debugattach.aspx from the rule allows visual studio to access the resource and solves the issue. So the rule ended up looking like this:

`<rule name="subpath-kill" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(cacherefresh|debugattach.aspx)$" negate="true" />
    <action type="AbortRequest" />
</rule>`

[See this post for related info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471110/what-is-debugattach-aspx-and-why-cant-the-server-find-it)